# Web Analytics not working

Tags: web-services, central-administration, service-application, web-analytics

I have SharePoint Server 2010 with Standard Client Access License and the Web Analytics isn’t populating. I have Web Analytics Data Processing Service and Web Analytics Web Service as started.

I get the following error:
"Data Last Updated: 11/15/2012 2:00:30 AM

There is no data available for this report. Here are some possible reasons: (1) Web Analytics has not been enabled long enough to generate data; (2) There is insufficient data to generate this report; (3) Data logging required for this report might not be enabled; (4) Data aggregation might not be enabled at the level required for this report."

Comment: When did you provision web analytics? Some initial info may be accessible after 24 hours after provisioning.

Comment: The SharePoint 2010 Server was setup a couple months ago.

Answer (score 2):

Check that monitoring is actually turned on:

> To verify that usage logging is enabled for desired event by using
>   Central Administration
>
> Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a
>   member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
>
> In Central Administration, on the Home page, click Monitoring.
>
> On Monitoring page, in the Reporting section, click Configure usage
>   and health data collection.
>
> On the Event Selection section, click all check boxes to select them,
>   and then click OK.

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266382(v=office.14).aspx

You can run the time job manually to get the data into the analytics report straight away by going into the 'Monitoring' section in Central Administration. There you will find a link under the 'Timer Jobs' heading called 'Review job definitions'. In there will be a whole load of job definitions, look for 'Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job' with the correct Web Application specified (for me it was on the 2nd page). Click the name of the job and click the 'Run Now' button.

Comment: I checked "Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job" and it is apparently running everyday. I hit Run Now and no change.

Comment: Did you check that monitoring is actually turned on? SharePoint needs to collect the logs to give your reports.

Comment: Where can I verify that?

Comment: It's in my answer, the quoted bit.

Comment: Everything is collected and the logs ARE being created, just Web Analytics not working completely.